# mySQL and PHP encodings

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, iconv

HI, I have a problem with this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `name` LIKE '%tést%'
```

the HMTL and the SQL table both have utf-8 encoding but unfortunately there is no `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` and I'm **NOT** able to use it.

I've tried with `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $name)` but the query matches only `test`.

I want to match all of these : `test, tést, tèst, tëst` (as it would work with `mysql_set_charset` )

**edit:**

`SET NAMES utf8` is nigher possible ... the database **is** with utf8 encoding, unfortunately the content is being filled from web without `mysql_set_charset` nor `SET NAMES`.

Currently if these functions are used the results are messed up.

`version()` **5.1.41-3ubuntu12.9**

**edit2:**

when I use `SET NAMES utf8` it matches only `tést` and they look like `tÃ©st`

when I use `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $name)` it matches only `test`

Comment: I'm Italian and we have a lot of é related trouble... but I got no troubles if:
- page encoding is set in UTF-8; - database table collation, table varchar or text collation as utf8_general_ci; and the connection itself in UTF-8.  I don't need to iconv nothing

Comment: I'm Bulgarian and I'm using utf8 a lot :) but the problem is that this particular table is filled by a script that had no `mysq_set_charset`

Comment: there isn't a way to "force" the incoming charset of that script? I don't know, I'm just supposing, if mysql force as default the utf-8 charset it could work...

Comment: Try to look at this, he force UTF-8 into my.cnf http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,28072,28072

Comment: All I could think of was to replace all these characters with underscore and get a query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%t_st%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the query try:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn);
```

****edits****

Apprently depending on MySQL version you might also be required to use:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $conn);
```

One final note, the database needs to be using the UTF-8 character set, to ensure this:

```
ALTER <database_name> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

****More edits****

After reading your edits I think that this is a issue with your HTML/PHP encoding.  On the page submitting the characters ensure that you set the headers properly:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

You should also set this via meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Then set the multibyte encoding with the [`mb_internal_encoding()`][1] function:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

By default PHP uses ISO-8859-1.
[1]: https://www.php.net/mb_internal_encoding

Comment: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn); ` messes up the results that the next query returns

Comment: `ALTER <database_name> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;` will change and there are 260 000 records in it :)

Comment: Seems like your MySQL is actually working properly, the issue sounds like it is the encoding of the HTML/PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I have just performed a quick test, and MySQL works as you expect it to work.

Perhaps it's the way you connect to the database, you could try executing SET NAMES 'utf8'; before performing the queries and see if that helps!

Also, please note that mysql_set_charset should take utf8, with no dash! See [an example from PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-set-charset.php#90014) to be sure!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try regexp with the desired regular expression  like

SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP #REGULAR EXP HERE#

Comment: the regular expression is not an option - the search string comes from the user

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SET NAMES?

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```